# How to add a dynamic URL to a form action in WordPress via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, action

I need to make a change to a WordPress plugin in how the filled in data is handled. When a user hits a submit button I need to set the form action to a generated URL.

The plugin already generates a URL in a hidden field, but I need the value to become the form action URL. (I'm quite unexperienced in JS)

The `#download` URL is the required URL needed to go to the form action.

```
    dataset.updateExistingChurn(), a(), dataset.updateTable(), dataset.updateBoxes();
    n = "";
    if (dataset.isValid()) {
        var n = "https://www.example.com/the-example-difference/";
        n += "?pdf=" + t(s)
    }
    jQuery("#download_url").val(n), "" != n || dataset.isValid() ? jQuery("#submission").removeClass("hide") : jQuery("#submission").addClass("hide")
}), jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    e()
}), dataset.updateExistingChurn(), dataset.updateTable(), dataset.updateBoxes()
```

})

The outcome is that on clicking submit they are directed to the URL. 
Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```
$(".submit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form').attr('action', "/url").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply... This doesn't work. I changed the .submit to .submission to match the #submission ID. How do I pull the custom URL in? Is it this bit that generates the custom URL?   var n = "https://www.example.com/the-example-difference/";
        n += "?pdf=" + t(s)

Comment: catch clic event on the submit button  ///
e.preventDefault() => stop native event ( form submit) ///
change action attribut by "/url" ( change this to what you want ), and submit the form ...